# ListView stopped accepting basic gestures after setting custom GestureListener

Tags: android, android-listview, gesture, onfling

I have created a GestureListener with a customized onFling method. I didn't override onScroll or onSingleTapConfirmed.

I created the listener like this:

```
   ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new CustomGestureListener(this));
        if (listView != null)
          listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
          {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
              if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
              {
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            }
          });
```

After that, the onFling event works fine but the single touch and scroll events are gone, my listview is dead. What should I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
          return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

For your second problem, use SimpleOnGestureListener. It has the methods that you want `onSingleTapConfirmed()` & `onFling()`.

Comment: Thanks, it cured the 'dead' state. The problem has evolved now :) If I use fling, it also detects the touch, so both event is fired. I'd like to make it distinct. If I touch with a single tap, then select the item, else the fling wins. How could I do it?

Comment: My listener is a SimpleOnGestureListener (CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener). If I use this code, my item gets highlighted but not gets pushed:   @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event)
  {
 
    ListView listView=(ListView)((InfoActivity)context).findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
  }

Comment: It will be better to create a  new question and state these new problems there with more detail. I will be more than happy to answer

Comment: Agreed, I was about to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new CustomGestureListener(this));
        if (listView != null)
          listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
          {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
              return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); //UPDATE HERE

            }
          });
```